# Create/change a file and source it - both in one line

Tags: source, here-document

I desire a command that creates/changes some file and then source that file, all in one line, in Bash.

It's important for me to know if it's possible (or why it isn't), as this could help saving a few lines in some long scripts by preventing the need in `source` or `./`.

For example, I have this code template to add aliases into `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
cat <<-"APPENDIX" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
    alias shortcut="command"
    alias shortcut="command"
APPENDIX
source /etc/bash.bashrc
```

How is it possible to save that `source /etc/bash.bashrc` line by making the file to be sourced the moment it is changed?

Note: I do have full permissions regarding `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution), [`tee`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html), and [`sponge` from moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
source <(cat /etc/bash.bashrc - <<-"APPENDIX" | tee >(sponge /etc/bash.bashrc)
    alias shortcut="command"
    alias shortcut="command"
APPENDIX
)
```

Probably don't do this, though.

---

Alternatively, with just [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution), reading from the file itself:

```
source $(cat <<-"APPENDIX" >> /etc/bash.bashrc ; echo /etc/bash.bashrc
    alias shortcut="command"
    alias shortcut="command"
APPENDIX
)
```

Probably don't do this either.

Comment: Both of those are longer in terms of characters, much more unclear, and don't even save any lines. So yeah, it's probably best to just stick with the original, straightforward method...

Comment: Of course they are. The question was whether it was *possible* in one line, and it wasn’t going to stop being asked until it got an answer, so here’s two approaches showing exactly that.

Comment: I'm just agreeing violently with your assessment of "don't do that".